# Add ID field to ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to add ID field to my form, and I'm getting so mad

Currently I have :

```
class ProductVideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVideo
        translatable_fields = get_translatable_fields(ProductVideoTranslation)
        fields = [
            "product",
            "id", #added!!!!
            "type",
            "placeholder",
        ] + translatable_fields
        widgets = {
            "placeholder": ImageInput(),
        }
        trans_fields_per_lang = get_trans_fields_per_lang(translatable_fields)
```

I added ID to fields, and the template is:

{{ video_formset.management_form }}

Why Is ID not displayed ??

actually, I just need display it, not updated.

Comment: is ID an editable field?

Comment: Is the auto id from django model, but I dont need edit it, I just want to show it.

Comment: It's a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Yea ok, but by default django will not display `editable=False` fields in forms.

What you are looking for is `disabled` param.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled